# Can a lagrangian submanifold of a 4-dimensional real space be diffeomorphic to sphere or real projective plane?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Is it possible to find a lagrangian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is diffeomorphic to $S^2$ or $\mathbb{R}P^2$?
As I have found, the answer is no for $S^2$, because $S^2$ is simply connected, while each lagrangian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is not simply connected. But I do not know how to prove it, I think it has to be simplier methods to show it.
The answer for $\mathbb{R}P^2$ I still do not know.

Comment: Are you taking the standard symplectic structure on $R^4$? Then such Lagrangians do not exist since there are no exact compact Lagrangians in ${\mathbb C}^n$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, what does the exact lagrangian submanifold mean?

Comment: See [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/vandyke/notes/242_notes/lecture4.pdf) for instance (as well as for the statement of Gromov's theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a consequence of [Weinstein's neighborhood Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313624/weinstein-neighborhood-theorem-for-lagrangians-with-legendrian-boundary#:%7E:text=Weinstein%27s%20neighborhood%20theorem%20says%20that,X%20be%20a%20closed%20Lagrangian.), one can rule out many closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ from being Lagrangian submanifolds (with respect to any symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$).  In fact, using it, I can rule out all oriented surfaces except $T^2$, and all non-orientable surfaces with odd Euler characteristic.  In particular, $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ cannot occur.

To see this, suppose $L$ is a closed surfaced embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a Lagrangian submanifold with respect to some symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$.  Weinstein's theorem gives an embedding of $T^\ast L \cong TL$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Now, the point is that $TL$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so the normal bundle of $L$ in $TL$ (which is isomorphic to $TL$), must be isomorphic to the normal bundle of $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

If $L$ is orientable, then the normal bundle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has trivial Euler class (Milnor-Stasheff, Corollary 11.4), while the Euler class of $L$ in $TL$ measures the Euler class.  Hence, if $L$ is orientable, $L$ must be a torus.

If $L$ is non-orientable, then the normal bundle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has trivial top Stiefel-Whitney class.  But this only happens in the tangent bundle $TL$ if $L$ has even Euler characteristic.

Comment: After composing this answer, googling led me to http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/ST-lectures/lecture4.pdf which uses the same ideas to reach the same conclusions.  It also references a result of Mohnke, Nemirovsky, and Schevschishin that the Klein bottle cannot occur, and a result of Givental that higher genus examples can actually arise.  It is not clear to me whether the four previously named authors are working in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the standard sympletic structure, or if they allow other symplectic forms.

Comment: I roughly understand your ideas, but, honestly, I am not familiar with Euler and Whitney classes yet. We have in our course Weinstein's neighborhood theorem, but other constructions you mentioned are not supposed to use, as I think. May be there is more elementary proof exactly for sphere and projective real plane, not for general closed surface. What do you think?

Comment: There certainly could be a more elementary proof in those cases, but nothing is coming to mind.  I'm know little symplectic geometry.  I googled, and realized that Weinstein's theorem could turn this into a topology problem, which is much more my expertise.